# SQL JOB schedule: how to skip certain month

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

I need a report that runs once on the following month below:
JAN,FEB,APR,MAY,JUL,AUG,OCT,NOV (*essentially skipping MAR, JUN, SEP and DEC*)

and this is how I do it (I had to have two schedules to achieve it: See screenshot below). and My question does my two-schedule method will get me what I need? is there a better way?
Will this still work in 2024, 2025 and so on?

thanks

The only difference between the schedule is the start date.

THE FIRST Schedule ( I am hoping this report will run on JAN APR JUL OCT)

[image: THE FIRST Schedule]

The second Schedule: ( And the second schedule, I am hoping it will run on FEB MAY AUG NOV)

[image: The second Schedule]

Comment: What is the type of task being executed? t-sql or OS or powershell etc?

Comment: storeproc, yes t-SQL

Comment: Why not check the month in your stored proc and not return anything on months you dont want the report and let the agent job run monthly, this will be much simpler and make it easier to change if you need to add or remove a month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply have a single job that executes monthly and in the t-sql job step

```
if month(getdate()) in (1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11)
begin
  exec...
end
```